# Add Role by code (REST API) in WSO2 Identity Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a question about Identity Server (v 5.5.0). I need add a new Role by code, exist an REST API for that?... or the only way is using "User Management SOAP API"?.

Note: in SCIM API cannot manage roles.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "in SCIM API cannot manage roles."? It can.

Comment: yes? how? I see only methods for manage user, group and me
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/apidocs/SCIM2-endpoints/

Comment: Groups means roles.

Comment: group is for roles too... ups... thanks Bee!

Comment: Identity Server has role concept but not a separate group concept at the moment. So the SCIM groups are mapped to the roles in the Identity Server